# Track TouchUpInside events in UIView

Tags: ios, swift

I have come to this problem and there's no solution to my knowledge. The solution must satisfy 2 requirements:
1. Catch `TouchUpInside` event, not `TouchUpOutside`. I need to take action as soon as finger touches the screen, not on lift up.
2. I need the location of the finger. That's why I am using `UIView` - whole screen is a target.

I tried:
1. Setting up my `UIViewController` as the delegate for `UITapGestureRecognizer`. Function `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` works but `locationOfTouch:inView:` always returns top left point as touched location.
2. Casting `UIView` to `UIControl` and calling `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` works too but doesn't return the location.
3. Subclassing `UIGestureRecognizer`. I tried this but it din't work because I don't know how to override `touchesBegan:WithEvent:`

I feel like custom gesture is the only way, can you please refer me to the manual or sample code? Or maybe other solutions? Thank you for reading.

Comment: Have you tried a UIPanGestureRecognizer instead?  Probably the simplest way to get continuous events while a finger is down.

Answer (score -1):

### `UIPanGestureRecognizer`

You can use `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to capture the event.

Add Gesture to your view.

```
//Method to call for your gesture.
self.panRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "panView:")

//Set delegate of Gesture
self.panRecognizer.delegate = self

//Add Gesture to the UIView
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.panRecognizer)
```

Track User event.

```
//Capture Gesture
func panView(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    switch recognizer.state {
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Began: break
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed: break
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended: break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

---

### `touchesBegan:`

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    //Get Touch Point
    let Point = touches.first!.locationInView(self.view)
}
```

Comment: I tried pan gesture. It didn't fire unless I dragged finger across the screen. I need to catch time and location of the finger when it lands on the screen and lifts off without dragging.

Comment: You need to try different states like `began, changed and ended`, then you can calculate point of touch on the view with `locationInView`

Comment: I tried your code thank you. The problems is that function `panView:` isn't called unless I drag my finger.

Comment: have you tried `touchesBegan` method? please see my updated answer.

Comment: For this I will need to subclass `UIGestureRecignizer` or `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and override the function. It should work. I'll report on my progress.

Comment: I can't build the project. Getting *Method does not override any method from its superclass* for the `touchesBegan` function.

Comment: Go to [NSChat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15942/nschat)  and ping me, I will guide you step by step.